# Garbled texts on WSL GUI application

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, wslg

Non-English characters are garbled on the [WSL GUI application](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps).

For example, I created a text file that contains foreign characters like this:

```
$ touch yoi.txt
$ echo "English한국어日本語" > yoi.txt
$ gedit yoi.txt
```

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTF8 characters in windows 10 bash terminal](https://superuser.com/questions/1108443/utf8-characters-in-windows-10-bash-terminal)

Comment: @harrymc Doubtful.  That question is for terminal-based apps.  This particular question is about garbled text in WSLg (gedit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not really garbled – that's just how Linux programs display characters that they *don't have any fonts for*. The hexadecimal digits inside each box correspond to Unicode codepoints for the character.  For example:

- 한 is [U+D55C](https://codepoints.net/U+D55C)
- 국 is U+AD6D

You should install more fonts in your Linux distribution. If you're using Ubuntu, `sudo apt install fonts-noto-cjk`.  The Noto font set supports many languages.

Or if you know that a specific font is needed, you can copy `.ttf` or `.otf` files to `~/.local/share/fonts/` in Linux.  You could even copy all the Windows fonts from C:\Windows\Fonts if you want.