# How to install fonts for all users using WSL?

Tags: bash, fonts, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Using WSL Bash, I followed both sets of the steps from [this question's answer](https://superuser.com/a/201899/121487) (only the first set of steps worked) but I get strange behaviour for the font.
The font does show up in my text editors but would not render properly. For example, the font I installed was sans-serif but would show up as a serif one. Additionally, the font doesn't show up in the Fonts settings.

If I use the font for [WSLTTY](https://github.com/mintty/wsltty), I get the following error message:

```
Font installation corrupt, using system substitute:
UbuntuMono NF
```

[image: WSLTTY startup error message]

How can I properly install the files from WSL Bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to how file permissions were applied when using WSL Bash.

The font file that was moved to `/mnt/c/Windows/Fonts` was missing the users with `Read & execute` permissions:

- `ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES`
- `ALL RESTRICTED APP PACKAGES`
- `Users`

Here are the full WSL Bash installation steps which must be run in an elevated terminal **(right-click and run as Administrator)**:

```bsh
# Let 'my font.ttf' be your font in the current working directory.

icacls.exe 'my font.ttf' /grant 'ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES':RX
icacls.exe 'my font.ttf' /grant 'ALL RESTRICTED APP PACKAGES':RX
icacls.exe 'my font.ttf' /grant Users:RX

mv 'my font.ttf' /mnt/c/Windows/Fonts/

reg.exe add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts" \
    /v "my font (TrueType)" \
    /t REG_SZ \
    /d "my font.ttf" \
    /f
```